# How to disable major release upgrade in Mojave?

Tags: mojave, catalina

I am thinking of not wanting to upgrade from Mojave to Catalina because, so far my setup & configurations of different apps like web-dev stuff and mobile-app development are all working and in proper order. It has taken me a long time to get to this point. Fear of breaking apps - esp 32-bit ones (if any) in the new upcoming version of MacOS has made me think of not going for the upgrade. How / Where do I disable a major release upgrade ?

Comment: We don't know for sure how Catalina might implement this, but Apple has never forced major upgrades on users. You may be nagged daily to download it, but it won't do it without your specific say so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supplements update are always better to have it and it will come automatically under Software Update if you press Check for update. You can choose whether to install it or not.

However, you will never get Catalina from Software Update if you are running Mojave. Catalina will be available in macOS store later as Apple has done for past OS. Later you download it if you want to install else for the whole year, Apple will never force to update you from running OS to a new OS. It's totally up to you.

Comment: Cool, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: This hasn’t been true in the past as Apple has shown upgrades as well as updates in the App Store to get to Mojave. I would encourage disabling automatic updates if you know you don’t want Catalina since Apple can change things even if it breaks from the past. One wrong click if you have a notification that updates are available and you’ll need to erase and install from a backup before Catalina was installed.

Answer (score 2):

To ignore all updates that start with "macOS Catalina":

```
sudo softwareupdate --ignore "macOS Catalina"
```

To reset all ignored updates:

```
sudo softwareupdate --reset-ignored
```

[Source](https://osxdaily.com/2019/10/16/hide-macos-catalina-software-update-mac/)

For more details, check out `man softwareupdate`:

```
     --ignore identifier ...
                 Manages the per-machine list of ignored updates. The
                 identifier is the first part of the item name (before the
                 dash and version number) that is shown by --list.  See
                 EXAMPLES.
```

Unfortunately, this does not ignore *only major releases* to the best of my knowledge, but it will stop the nags until disabled. (I too am interested in the ability to ignore only `10.xx.0` major releases...)